# swiftmailer php file doesn't execute, issue is on line 6

Tags: php, swiftmailer

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp', 25);
$transport->setUsername('name');
$transport->setPassword('password');
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$message = new Swift_Message('There must be some new subject');
$message->setFrom(['host' => 'myname']);
$message->setTo(['some@gmail.com', 'other@gmail.com' => 'and_his_name']);
$message->setBody('Here is the message itself');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Problem on the sixth line. Don't even know why this thing didn't work but all that below sixth lines doesn't execute.

Comment: Whats the error? Add try catch to check the ssame.

Comment: what error you get? can you post?